# How to declare not used parameter in the function

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my code, I have to split the key and value from a request params object to validate the value via `ObjectID`. So, I used map over an array of entries and destructured the key and value so I could test the value. But I'm getting the error:

> '_key' is defined but never used

How should I fix it?

```
export const validateObjectId = (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    Object.entries(request.params).map(([_key, param]) => {
        if (!ObjectId.isValid(param)) {
            return errorConstants.sendErrorResponse(response, errorConstants.invalid_object_id);
        }
    });
    next();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't using the key, only the value, why not just use `Object.values` instead of `Object.entries`?

Also note that since you aren't using the resulting array, you should probably use `.forEach` instead of `.map`, and the return value isn't being used, so there's no need to `return`:

```
export const validateObjectId = (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    Object.values(request.params).forEach((param) => {
        if (!ObjectId.isValid(param)) {
            errorConstants.sendErrorResponse(response, errorConstants.invalid_object_id);
        }
    });
    next();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can tell, there doesn't appear to be a mistake. However, I'm guessing your linter doesn't like you declaring `_key` without using it. This is where the array-destructuring syntax is fighting your linter. Another approach you could do is just not destructure:

```js
Object.entries(request.params).map((pair) => {
  const param = pair[1];
  // do the rest
});
```

Comment: I was a second or two faster than @CertainPerformance but `Object.values` is better in this case (since it saves you a little bit a work not declaring the variable). I'd go for that instead